# cakephp find all with several tables

Tags: cakephp-2.0

My problem is I am trying to get data from 5 different tables all the tables are related and I can create a sql query to get what I want. Here it is.

```
SELECT accounts.account_number, trailers.id, members.first_name, balances.balance, loans.loan_description, delinquent_loans.days_delinquent, delinquent_loans.amount_delinquent, delinquent_loans.next_contact, delinquent_loans.last_contact
FROM accounts, trailers, members, balances, accounts_trailers, loans, delinquent_loans
WHERE delinquent_loans.loan_id = loans.id
AND loans.accounts_trailer_id = accounts_trailers.id
AND accounts_trailers.account_id = accounts.id
AND accounts_trailers.trailer_id = trailers.id
AND accounts.member_id = members.id
AND balances.accounts_trailer_id = accounts_trailers.id
AND members.first_name
REGEXP '^[a-l]'
ORDER BY delinquent_loans.days_delinquent DESC
```

What I don't understand is how to this query in cakePHP the proper way.  I'm sure I can just use the query function and paste the previous query but I would like to do this the right way.

```
public function listAL(){
    $this->recursive = -1;
    $conditions = array('`DelinquentLoan`.`loan_id` = `Loan`.`id`', 
                                '`Loan`.`accounts_trailer_id` = `AccountsTrailer`.`id`', 
                                '`AccountsTrailer`.`account_id` = `Account`.`id`', 
                                '`AccountsTrailer`.`trailer_id` = `Trailer`.`id`', 
                                '`Account`.`member_id` = `Member`.`id`', 
                                '`Balance`.`accounts_trailer_id` = `AccountsTrailer`.`id`', 
                                '`Member`.`first_name` regexp \'^[a-l]\'');
    $fields = array('`Account`.`account_number`, 
                            `Trailer`.`id`, `Member`.`first_name`, 
                            `Balance`.`balance`, 
                            `Loan`.`loan_description`, 
                            `Delinquent_loan`.`days_delinquent`, 
                            `Delinquent_loan`.`amount_delinquent`, 
                            `Delinquent_loan`.`next_contact`, 
                            `Delinquent_loan`.`last_contact`');
    return $this->find('all', array('fields'=> $fields, 
                                                'order'=>array('`DelinquentLoan`.`days_delinquent` desc'),
                                                'conditions'=> $conditions));
}
```

Any help with this is appreciated.  I have looked at other sites and forums but to no avail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I think this is what you're searching for:

```
Model::saveAssociated(array $data = null, array $options = array())
```

Found in the Cookbook [Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

If the associations between models are well done, I don't see whats the problems just by using a simple find('all',...), maybe you should specify better what you are trying to do with your models and how are the associations between them.

Probably the Containable behaviour may help you. It's for cutting and filtering information when performing a "find":

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html